# Python: Venv has different pip version than Windows that doesn't allow installing packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed Python 3.9 and have a problem with installing packages via pip.

`python -V` returns `Python 3.9.1`

`pip -V` returns `pip 20.2.3 from c:\users\joasa\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

When I do `pip install numpy` for example, I see numpy normally installed, when I later type `pip freeze`.

In PyCharm -> Project Intrepreter I create a VirtualEnv Environment with Base Interpreter `C:\Users\joasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe`.

However, when I activate my venv and then do `pip -V`, what I see is

`pip 20.3.1 from C:\Users\joasa\Path-to-project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9) (venv)`

And if I do `pip install numpy` in my venv, I see this warning:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/pip/
```

I have added in my `Environmental Variables-> System Variables-> Path`, both

`C:\Users\joasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`
`C:\Users\joasa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts`

Why does the venv get a different version of pip and why I get this messages and can't install anything? I can't even downgrade it to pip 20.2.3 because I get this warning message. How can I solve it?

Comment: Never use any `pip` (or `pip3`, etc.) scripts directly. Instead, always use the surefire way by calling the _pip_ module for a specific Python interpreter explicily: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...`. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: thanks man! didn't know it was so simple, very useful link.